# Using Excel's INDEX Function with COLUMN and MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an INDEX function combined with MATCH, COLUMN, and a Data Validated Cell.

This is the function I have written, but it throws there was an error that there is something wrong.

```
=INDEX(ShipsData,MATCH(B3,ShipsData[Name],0),COLUMN(ShipsData[Max_Level]))
```

This works, but it is not as future proof as I would like.

```
=INDEX(ShipsData,MATCH(B3,ShipsData[Name],0),13)
```

I should point out neither of these works as the maximum for a data validation between condition, the second works when placed in a cell.

Additional Information:

ShipsData is the name of the table, B3 is a Data Validated cell with a drop down of all possible ships, and there are Two columns in the table named Name and Max_Level.

What I am trying to do is validate the level of a ship so that it is between (inclusive) it's minimum level (1) and it's maximum level which varies per ship.

If you need any more information I can provide it.

Edit:

I solved part of the problem, the formula now completes in a cell, there was a typo in the table header Max_Level.

However when I past this formula into the data validation, it gives me a message about 'We found a problem with this formula' and it will not insert, however the function works in a cell now.

Comment: It does not seem that the Data Validation on B3 has anything to do with the problem in your formula; whether B3 is a data validation cell or not, its value will impact your INDEX formula in the same way. It looks like the problem is that you are referring to ShipsData[Name] and ShipsData[Max_Level]. I have not seen this in an Excel formula before. Is it meant to refer to a specific column of a named 2D array? Because that doesn't work when I test it.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I believe they're Structured References, i.e. for a Table named ShipsData and columns named Name and Max_Level within that Table.

Comment: @XORLX ah - I missed that this was in reference to an actual Excel Table; thought it was a Named range. It looks like this should work, and if it's not I assume invalid references of ShipsName / ShipsData are being passed to the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, your formula shows a #REF error.

Your problem in the first instance is that the Column argument for the INDEX function is looking for the column number in the table; and your reference is returning the absolute column number of the Max_Level column.  So this will work if and only if the table starts in column 1 (column A).

Try this:

```
=INDEX(ShipsData,MATCH(B3,ShipsData[Name],0),COLUMN(ShipsData[Max_Level])-COLUMN(ShipsData)+1)
```

If your formula is showing "The formula you typed contains an error", then it may be that you have moved something around such that Max_Level  (or Name) is no longer a part of the Table.

You can check this by, in some blank cell, typing:

```
=ShipsData[
```

and seeing the column headers available showing up in the dropdown.

e.g:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe (at least in Excel 2010) that Custom Data Validation formulas will accept Structured References. Hence the Name Manager workaround I outline. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @XORLX  I only addressed the problem of the formula itself on the worksheet.  I thought he had figured out that structured references could not be used directly in a Data Validation list, which your response has nicely addressed.

Comment: @XORLX None necessary at all

Comment: I managed to get it working in cell, there was a space in the Max_Level, however when I paste it into the data validation it still throws 'We found a problem with this formula' message.

Comment: The line you said works in a cell, but not in a data validation call.

Comment: @chriscisco As pointed out by XORLX you cannot use structured references in a data validation formula

Comment: Ok thanks, I am in excel 365 so I wasn't sure if that was still the case.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Data Validation for cell A1, assuming *Name* and *Max_Level* (excluding their headers) occupy the ranges E2:E10 and F2:F10 respectively :

`=AND(A1>=1,A1<=INDEX($F$2:$F$10,MATCH($B$3,$E$2:$E$10,0)))`

If you prefer to stay with Structured Table References, which is of course more dynamic, then you will first need to go to Name Manager (*Formulas* tab) and define *Limit* as:

`=INDEX(ShipsData[Max_Level],MATCH(Sheet5!$B$3,ShipsData[Name],0))`

after which the above Custom Data Validation becomes:

`=AND(A1>=1,A1<=Limit)`

Regards