# Alternative to VLOOKUP with "qualitative qualfiers" (i.e. text, etc.)

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I've got List:

```
Security:       Country of Issue:    Currency:
Stock           Greece                USD
Stock           USA                  USD
Option          Great Britain        GBP
Bond            Greece               EUR
```

I want to find the currency of the stock in Greece. Normally I would use `VLOOKUP` but I assume it cannot process this request. What other functions are there to find the underlying currency?

Comment: [Index/Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965182/using-excels-index-function-with-column-and-match#31965853) sounds like it may do what you want

Comment: You could use vlookup choose: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-vlookup-to-the-left-using-choose